# Using BigQuery for logs analysis

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to do logs analysis with BigQuery. Specifically, I have an appengine app and a javascript client that will be sending log data to BigQuery. In bigquery, I'll store the full log text in one column but also extract important fields into other columns. I then want to be able to do adhoc queries over those columns.

Two questions:

1) Is BigQuery particularly good or particularly bad at this use case?
2) How do I setup revolving logs? I.e. I want to only store the last N logs or the last X GB of log data. I see delete is not supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Just so you know, there is an excellent demo of moving App Engine Log data to BigQuery via App Engine MapReduce called log2bq (http://code.google.com/p/log2bq/)
2. Re: "use case" - Stack Overflow is not a good place for judgements about best or worst, but BigQuery is used internally at Google to analyse really really big log data.
3. I don't see the advantage of storing full log text in a single column. If you decide that you must set up revolving "logs," you could ingest daily log dumps by creating separate BigQuery tables, perhaps one per day, and then delete the tables when they become old. See https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/delete for more information on the Table.delete method.

Comment: 3. The advantage of storing the full text in one column and extracting some useful info from it and storing that in other columns is that we can see the original, pre processed log entry if we need to. To setup the revolving logs, if we use one table per day - how do we query over multiple days?

Comment: Great question, if the table schemas are the same, you can use a query like this: SELECT f1, f2 FROM table_day1, table_day2, table_day3;

Comment: Hmmm. Any limitations to that? What's the Mac number if tables? If I want 60 day revolving logs then I need to have 60 table clauses and every day those will change? I guess I can script it when running queries.

Comment: You could revolve between just two tables. Select a subset (last 48 hours) from one table and insert it into another at the beginning of the day.

Comment: @aloo There is no limit to the amount of tables you express in an SQL statement, but the maximum query length is currently 10KB.

Answer (score 1):

After implementing this - we decided to open source the framework we built for it. You can see the details of the framework here: http://blog.streak.com/2012/07/export-your-google-app-engine-logs-to.html

Comment: The blog post link is no longer working. "Sorry, the page you were looking for in this blog does not exist."

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Google App Engine (Google Cloud) project's logs to be in BigQuery, Google has added this functionality built in to the new Cloud Logging system. It is a beta feature known as "Logs Export"
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/install/logs_export

They summarize it as:

> Export your Google Compute Engine logs and your Google App Engine logs to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, a Google BigQuery dataset, a Google Cloud Pub/Sub topic, or any combination of the three.

We use the "Stream App Engine Logs to BigQuery" feature in our Python GAE projects. This sends our app's logs directly to BigQuery as they are occurring to provide near real-time log records in a BigQuery dataset.

There is also a page describing how to use the exported logs.
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/using_exported_logs

When we want to query logs exported to BigQuery over multiple days (e.g. the last week), you can use a SQL query with a `FROM` clause like this:

```
FROM
    (TABLE_DATE_RANGE(my_bq_dataset.myapplog_,
      DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7, 'DAY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))
```

Comment: Very useful. Note that to use `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` legacy SQL dialect must be enabled. The current syntax is slightly different https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694?hl=en#multiple&zippy=%2Cin-this-article