# Ingesting logs into bigquery from a python script

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-bigquery

I want to ingest logs from an appengine app to bigquery without using appengine mapreduce ?

Comment: So, what is the specific programming question? Do you have any problem?

Comment: I am able to do OAuth dance to access BigQuery and send data from a local file to a table (already created) in BigQuery.
Now, I want to send logs from app engine log store to a table in BigQuery using Python.

Comment: I saw 'log2bq' application that ingest logs into bigquery using mapreduce pipeline, but I don't want to use mapreduce.
Right now I'm not able to figure out how to send logs from the app engine logstore to the bigquery table.

Comment: Also I want to send the logs directly from the app engine log store to bigquery.
I don't want to first store them into google cloud storage and then send the logs from cloud storage to the bigquery.

Comment: you should edit your question to provide the additional altogether instead of the comments. It will make it more specific and prone to get answers.

Comment: Just to be clear, the log2bq doesn't actually use MapReduce... it uses a Mapper function, but not a Reduce step. Also, I have no idea why you wouldn't want to use the Mapper to get to the App Engine logs - it simplifies your code tremendously!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using BigQuery for logs analysis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405704/using-bigquery-for-logs-analysis)

Answer (score 1):

We've open sourced a Java implementation of migrating appengine logs to bigquery here: http://blog.streak.com/2012/07/export-your-google-app-engine-logs-to.html

Answer (score 0):

See the bigquery docs [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/developers_guide#localimport). You can post a multi-part http request that has the data you want to add to the table. If you are doing an append you won't need to provide the schema.

Comment: :I need to send the app engine loggging data to bigquery.
I don't want to store the logs to a local file and then upload the local file to bigquery, instead I want to directly send the appengine logs to bigquery.

Comment: I want to know how to access the appengine logs and then export them to bigquery.

Comment: The 'local file' import request doesn't have to be a local file. It is just data that you send in a multi-part HTTP POST request. If you have access to your appengine logs, you can send them to BigQuery via this mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a Python runtime implementation called "log2bq" that demonstrates how to ingest App Engine logs into BigQuery: http://code.google.com/p/log2bq/

Answer (score 0):

Google has recently released a (BETA) feature called "Google Cloud Logging: Logs Export"
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/install/logs_export

They summarize it as:

> Export your Google Compute Engine logs and your Google App Engine logs to a Google Cloud Storage bucket, a Google BigQuery dataset, a Google Cloud Pub/Sub topic, or any combination of the three.

I haven't tried out all of the functionality provided by this new service but...

We have recently started using the "Stream App Engine Logs to BigQuery" feature in our Python GAE project. This sends our app's logs directly to BigQuery as they are occurring to provide near real-time log records in a BigQuery dataset.